# How to best deconstruct huge class into several sub classes PHP / OOP

Tags: php

First of all, everything I want the Code to do, it does. This question is solely about Code Structure, OOP and respective Design Patterns.

Ok, so I have a javascript front end and a PHP backend.
I access several functions inside a huge Event Class, with several AJAX php files.

one of them accesses the functionality inside the Event Class like this:

```
$event = new Event();
$event->storeFormValues($_POST);
$event->newEvent();
```

Before I started thinking about how to better structure the code, the Event Class had over 600 lines of Code and functions giving me back database informations about the event.

Now I devided the Event Class into 2 parts, a Event class which basically looks like this (it already extends a small connection class, which handles the mysql connection):

```
class Event extends Connection {

    public $eventHead = null; // event title
    public $eventBody = null;
    public $eventID = null;
    ...

    public function __construct($data = array()) {
        if (isset($data['eventHead'])) {
        $this->eventHead = stripslashes(strip_tags($data['eventHead']));
        }
    ...
    }

    public function storeFormValues($params) {
    //store the parameters
    $this->__construct($params);
    }
}
```

and a NewEvent Class, which has all the functions I need to add a new Event in the Database. (still about 500 lines of code).

I made a seperate class for all the functions that give me back information about events:

```
class EventInformation extends Event {

    public function getEvent() {  
    }

    public function getParts() { 
    }
}
```

For me, this was clear, the EventInformation Class inherits the functionality from the Event Class, so I can first store the eventID via the storeFormValues function and then access the function like this in my ajax file:

```
$information = new EventInformation();
$information->storeFormValues($_POST);
$data = $information->getEvent();
```

But now I'm stuck on how to further deconstruct my NewEvent Class, which has all the functions I need for adding a new Event like I previously stated. It now (after I seperated the Event Class into two parts looks like this:

```
$event = new NewEvent();
$event->storeFormValues($_POST);
$event->newEvent();
```

the newEvent function inside my NewEvent Class looks like this:

```
public function newEvent() {
    try {
        parent::mySQL_connect();
        $this->connection->beginTransaction();
        $this->setOldEventPosition();
        $this->setNewEventPosition();
        $this->findEmptyEventSpot();
        $this->updateOldEvents();
        $this->insertEventData();
        $this->insertPartData();
        $this->establishNewEventConnection();
        $this->establishEventPath();
        $this->connection->commit();
        return true;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $this->connection->rollback();
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Ok... so all these functions are kind of long in themselves and could be several classes... but how do I do this the right way?

I thought about creating a class for every function of my newEvent function(since they all kind of do different stuff). But all the functions kind of depend on variables, that the other functions set.

I especially see a Problem with my newEvent function... because how do I let it extend from all the Classes I created?

it would need to look like this (which is not possible):

```
EventActions extends setOldEventPosition extends setNewEventPosition, etc...
```

If you know where I'm getting at...

Or should I don't make a seperate class for the newEvent Function and just add a new Event in my ajax file like this:

```
$event = new NewEvent();
$event->storeFormValues($_POST);
$event->mySQL_connect();
$oldEventPosition = new OldEventPosition();
$oldEventPosition->getOldEventPosition();
$oldEventPosition->setOldEventPosition();
$newEventPosition = new EventPosition();
...
```

But I really would like to have my newEvent function in a seperate Class.
How do I do this?

If I let all the classes, associated with creating a new event, extend the "previous" class, like this:

```
class OldEventPosition extends NewEvent {
}
class NewEventPosition extends OldEventPosition {
}
...
```

my class (where the newEvent function sits) would need to extend the last class in this chain... and this kind of seems not right to me, or is it?

Comment: This is much too much code for a question. Also there are multiple questions in one. Please strip out anything that does not contribute value to the question and state a clear, understandable question. What is your problem? I didn't get it. Are you just wondering about long code files? Is this question about a performance problem or about aesthetics?

Comment: You don't have to use 1 big object for everything. Think of real world objects,... like Event and EventInformation are different objects, don't let one exetend the other, pass dependencies: `Dependency Injection Pattern`.

Comment: Thank you so much Dan, I looked into Dependency Injection more deeply and it was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes are meant to encapsulate and group functionalities logically.

You SQL connector for example should be a class on its own that is initialized and the connection set up before passing this object to an instance of `Event`.

It does not make much sense to write classes for specific functions. What is the real logical difference between `NewEvent`, `EventPosition` and `OldEventPosition`? Maybe a database utility class with additional helper functions is useful for you.

Comment: EventPosition, OldEventPosition (and many others) are just the functions that set up the logic, they get the data I need out of different mysql tables and prepare them, so i can insert a new event at a specific new location.
A database utility class in this case, would be very large as well.